# interface an lcd through rs232 interface

Tags: lcd, serial-port, intel-atom, rs232

Linux has character device file representing serial port /dev/ttys*. I can simply open , read , write , close a serial port using system calls in my c program. I am working on a board which has an Intel atom processor. The board runs on fedora, it has 2 rs232 interface.

Is the above mentioned port real or virtual (like socket)?

What I don't get is, how to associate this serial port with the rs232 interface, I want to connect a LCD display to the rs232 and be able to write data to the display, using USB is last choice since I am building a portable medical kit, I don't want it to be power hungry.
Any sample code, links of how to code such interface is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, RS-232 port should be automatically associated with its /dev/tty entry if the correct kernel modules related to the serial interface are enabled. There's nothing much to do. You'll have to check with board vendor for correct modules which need to be enabled as that depends heavily on the way ports themselves are implemented.

As for connecting display, in general it could work fine by just sending text, but to do that, you'd need an RS-232 enabled display. I haven't seen any, but they could exist. Instead displays are usually connected (more or less) directly to I/O pins of the processor in embedded computers.

What you need to send via RS-232 only depends on what the display expects and I can't help you much there since I don't know which display you'll be using.